# JPA Repository Spring Boot: Force Read from DB instead of cache

Tags: mysql, groovy, spring-data-jpa

We are using Spring JPARepository. We are having different batch process running *under separate VMs (separate applications, separate deployments*) and operating on the same underlying DB Table instance.

Batch 1: 
    Step 1: Inserting in DB.Table1; 
    Step 2: Time consuming complex biz task; 
    Step 3: Updating the same row in DB.Table1;

Batch 2: Updating same row in DB.Table1.

When DB row is updated by Batch 2 process in between start/end of Batch 1, Batch 1 needs to read from DB and act accordingly. But instead it is reading from cache. 
            `Entity findById(Long id)`

Marking the entity `@Cacheable(false)` will impact all operation on this entity as a whole, which will be less performant and I don't want to do.

What will be the other way of achieving the same at specific operation level?

**EDIT** - Is there any way, in this case, other than using Native SQL query to Force Read the LATEST data in Table1.Col1? The following didn't work:
1. Using `repository.saveAndFlush()` during Batch 1.Step 1 doesn't help in reading back the latest data Step 3 `repository.findById(id)`
 2. `entityManager.refresh(entity)` didn't work 
 3. Since each process is running under different context, using `LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT` on Batch 2.Step 1 won't help

Comment: Are Batch 1 or Batch 2 processes transactional? That is, could it be an issue of your Table1 updates in Batch 1 are not being committed and are therefore unrelated to what Batch 2 is trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the native read to be the only solution till date which is working as expected.

Comment: I Tried many things even this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69310530/entitymanager-refresh-method-does-not-refresh-but-resets but your pure native answer works like a charm