# EntityManager refresh() method does not refresh but resets

Tags: hibernate, jpa, entitymanager, hibernate-jpa

The `em.refresh(person)` in the following code does not work. Rather than refreshing the `person` with a fresh value from database, it resets (undo or discards) the changes made in the cache. I am not able to understand why?

```
em.getTransaction().begin();
        
Person person = em.find(Person.class, 2L); //Person[id=2L, age=23]
person.setAge(24); 
System.out.println(person.getAge()); //it prints 24
        
//Person with id=2 in database gets modified concurrently somehow,
//its age becomes 25 in PERSON table (by an SQL update for example "UPDATE person SET age=25 WHERE id=2")

em.refresh(person); // attempts to load fresh value from database with a SELECT...
System.out.println(person.getAge()); //it prints 23, rather than 25, why?
        
em.getTransaction().commit();
em.close();
```

Could someone help me understand this behavior by the `refresh()` method of `EntityManager`?

Comment: May be use flush before refresh?

Comment: You are making these tests inside a transaction and transactions are generally with 'repeatable reads'. Unless the database was updated (e.g. doing a flush ) it will return the same value on the 2nd select

Comment: @Alien and @Guillaume : Issuing a `em.flush()` before `em.refresh(person)` will issue an `UPDATE...` updating the `age=24` in the database, so with `em.refresh(person)` I will not get `age=25`, I'll get it `age=24`. So the `em.flush()` before  `em.refresh(person)` is not going to help to get the updated data from database.

Comment: @Guillaume `em.refresh(person)` is not giving a repeatable-read, it is doing an undo. It is discarding the changes made in the cache (`age` changed from 23 to 24) and taking the `person` object back to when it was first loaded in the cache (`age=23`). So `em.refresh(person)` is not giving a repeatable read either, it is doing an reset/undo of `person`.

Comment: @skip Are you sure that changes `UPDATE person SET age=25 WHERE id=2` were committed? By the way, what database do you use?

Comment: @SternK Yes, the auto-commit mode was on by default. After the update, checked it in database from a different session as well. The `UPDATE person SET age=25 WHERE id=2` indeed had committed the change and updated the age to 25.

Comment: @SternK I used the example with MySQL 8. I've updated the question with a screenshot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to see changes made from other transactions while inside a transaction you need to change the isolation level to READ_COMMITTED

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.isolation">TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED</property>
```

A few definitions to clarify the discussion:

- **Repeatable read**: essentially means that within a transaction the database will see the same value, unless the data was modified within that transaction
- **Hibernate flush**: the modifications made in the session (e.g. `person.setAge(24);`) are not visible by the database until they are flushed. A flush occurs when calling em.flush, committing or, typically, when executing a query such as `select * from Person where name=...` but not when calling refresh()
- **Hibernate refresh**: reading the data from the database and updating the session/1st level cache with that data.

So basically:

- You're modifying the age by calling setAge() but that change is not flushed, hence not visible by the database
- You're updating from another session but that change is not visible either because the transactions are isolated (unless using READ_COMMITTED)
- When refresh is called the database is not aware that setAge() was called and it isolates the update from another transaction, so it shows 23

Comment: I understand that, but `em.refresh(person)` is not even giving a repeatable-read, it is just resetting/undoing the changes made in the cache, setting the `age` back to 23, the `age` when the `person` was first loaded into the cache from database.

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect but that's what repeatable read means: you're first reading 23, then you're reading a 2nd time (when you refresh) and it reads 23 again, because transactions are isolated by default. You keep mentioning the cache, do you have 2nd-level cache enabled?

Comment: Repeatable-Read means that data will be read from the cache, and in the cache the `age` has been updated to 24, so repeatable-read means the `age` should been read as 24 not 23. `age` returning a value 23 means that state of `person` after the `em.refresh(person)` has been reset back to its initial state when it was first loaded from database into cache. So the `em.refresh(person)` has basically undone any changes made in the cache and not given a repeatable-read.

Comment: No, I have not enabled second-level cache. It's just the first-level cache.

Comment: Am I not correct about the repeatable-read? Should repeatable-read not have retuned a 24 for `age`?

Comment: I have updated my answer, repeatable-read is in the context of databases. Refresh is not reading from the 1st-level cache

Comment: Correct, the reason why the `age` wasn't updating to 25 was because the default transaction isolation level of MySQL is REPEATABLE_READ. I changed the isolation level to READ COMMITTED and the same code worked just fine. Thanks.